# Check if elements of an array are exclusive to other multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

From what I know, elements in array of numpy package can be discriminated through `np.isin` function.

For instance:

```
In:
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
B = np.array([6,7,8,9,1])
C = np.array([6,7,1,2,4])
~np.isin(A , [B, C])

Out:
array([ False, False, True, False, True])
```

In this case, since 3 and 5 don't exist in either of those compared arrays, I understand the output would be performed as shown above.

But if I make it a little different like this:

```
In:
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
B = np.array([6,7,8,9,1,3])
C = np.array([6,7,1,2,4])
~np.isin(A , [B, C])

Out:
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

Rather then what I expected:

```
array([False, False, False, False,  True])
```

After a test I've known that placing a np.nan in array `C` would work fine.

But is there any efficient way to check if elements in array `A` are not present in other arrays whose shapes are different?

Comment: You can't put nan into an array of integers. Please show your actual test.

Comment: Also, you can pass in an `invert=True` parameter to flip the mask a tad faster.

Comment: You can just concatenate all the test elements in a single array: `~np.isin(A, np.concatenate((B,C)))`.

Comment: i think since the B and C are uneven, so np is facing difficulty in broadcasting. i think the solution would be to flatten both arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is with how you pass in the second parameter `[B, C]`. The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) say

> The values against which to test each value of element. This argument is flattened if it is an array or array_like. See notes for behavior with non-array-like parameters.

And the notes:

> `element` and `test_elements` are converted to arrays if they are not already. If `test_elements` is a `set` (or other non-sequence collection) it will be converted to an object array with one element, rather than an array of the values contained in `test_elements`. This is a consequence of the array constructor’s way of handling non-sequence collections. Converting the set to a list usually gives the desired behavior.

What this means in your case is that the first example, which contains `B` and `C` of equal length gets correctly interpreted as a 2D array of integers (which is then raveled to 1D). In the second example, `B` and `C` have different sizes. Since you can't have a ragged array, the result becomes an object array containing two elements, each of which is an array. Since none of your `A` elements is an array, all the comparisons are `False`.

A workaround is to pre-construct the expected input properly:

```
np.isin(A, np.concatenate((B, C)), invert=True)
```